# 3DES Decryption Sometimes Different

Tags: ios, encryption, 3des

I'm having a problem using the CCCrypt function to simply encrypt/decrypt a chunk of data.

My platform is iOS 8 in Xcode 6.

What I'm doing is, I convert a test string to NSData format and pass it into a wrapper function I made.  The return of that function is the encrypted data.  I take that encrypted data and then pass it back into the function specifying that it should be decrypted.

- **Sometimes** the value comes back decrypted properly.
- Sometimes it's complete junk.
- Sometimes said junk is not the same (but sometimes it is).
- Sometimes I'm seeing the correct string but with extra junk at the end of it.

I wrapped the use of the encryption/decryption function in a loop so I can see the inconsistent behavior more closely.

**The Implementation**

```
NSString* unencryptedString = @"Testtest";
NSData* unencryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)[unencryptedString UTF8String] length:[unencryptedString length]];
NSData* encryptedData = nil;
NSData* decryptedData = nil;

for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    encryptedData = [NSData tripleDesEncrypt:YES Data:unencryptedData error:&err];
    decryptedData = [NSData tripleDesEncrypt:NO Data:encryptedData error:&err];

    NSLog(@"unencrypted: %@, encrypted: %s\n\ndecrypted: %s", unencryptedString, encryptedData.bytes, decryptedData.bytes);

    if(err)
        NSLog(@"error: %@", err);
}
```

**The Function**

```
+(NSData*)tripleDesEncrypt:(BOOL)encrypt
                  Data:(NSData *)inputData
                 error:(NSError **)error
{
    NSString* tripleDesKeyString = @"ABCd@Efghijklmno";
    NSData* tripleDesKeyData = [tripleDesKeyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const void* tripleDesKey = [tripleDesKeyData bytes];

    NSString* ivKeyString =   @"012345678901234567890123";
    NSData* keyData = [ivKeyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const void* ivKey = [keyData bytes];
    NSAssert(keyData.length == kCCKeySize3DES, @"tripleDesEncrypt; the keyData is an invalid size");

    NSNumber* pOptions = [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCCOptionPKCS7Padding];
    int options = [pOptions intValue];
    size_t dataMoved;

    unsigned encryptionBufferLen = inputData.length + kCCBlockSize3DES;
    void* encryptedBuffer = malloc(encryptionBufferLen);
    memset(encryptedBuffer, 0, encryptionBufferLen);

    CCCryptorStatus
    result = CCCrypt(encrypt ? kCCEncrypt : kCCDecrypt, // operation
                     kCCAlgorithm3DES, // Algorithm
                     options, // options
                     tripleDesKey, // key
                     tripleDesKeyData.length, // keylength
                     ivKey,// iv
                     inputData.bytes, // dataIn
                     inputData.length, // dataInLength,
                     encryptedBuffer, // dataOut
                     encryptionBufferLen, // dataOutAvailable
                     &dataMoved); // dataOutMoved

    NSData* outputData = [NSData dataWithBytes:encryptedBuffer length:dataMoved];
    free(encryptedBuffer);

    return outputData;
}
```

**The Output**

*(I'll only run a few iterations of the output to show the weird differences.)*

```
unencrypted: Testtest, encrypted: jgüb  -A7‘œåÅKX
decrypted: ¿Ïh5¥√‚qN;1»Í

unencrypted: Testtest, encrypted: ¥⁄˘qÓırS{ÿœ•
decrypted: Æ˛ {íÒ⁄ñè–%4¢‚g

unencrypted: Testtest, encrypted: jgüb  -A7‘œåÅKX
decrypted: Testtest∞¸yå`j/private/tmp/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.47124028-EC86-4CC0-8CA2-7DCDED3994B1.launchd_sim/syslogsock


unencrypted: Testtest, encrypted: /Âò◊9ƒ˘=m]˚†%À
decrypted: u‹z©tÙÁ∑<%ˇπØ•

unencrypted: Testtest, encrypted: jgüb  -A7‘œåÅKX
decrypted: ¿Ïh5¥√‚qN;1»Í

unencrypted: Testtest, encrypted: jgüb  -A7‘œåÅKX
decrypted: Testtest
```

Comment: Oh, also, I'm receiving no errors back as a result.  It's always a success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key is only 16 bytes long. 3DES keys need to be 24 bytes long. So what is happening is that whatever random 8 bytes happen to be in memory after your `tripleDesKey` get used as the rest of key. Who knows what those bytes actually belong to, and their value could very well change in between the encryption call to `tripleDesEncrypt` and the decryption call. Different key = different encryption. That would produce the cases where your decryption didn't give back the original plaintext.

(BTW, I don't know why the `NAssert` on the key length isn't firing. Might you be compiling in release mode, or similar?)

Solution: increase the length of your key to 24 bytes.

As for the garbage you see at the end of the plaintext after decryption: How are you printing the result? The decrypted plaintext won't have a trailing null char, so if you're using something like `printf` then you will need to put a null char at the end of the plainext before printing it. Otherwise the system will happily output the characters after the end of your plaintext until it happens reaches a null char.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.  The Assertion is not failing because  "012345678901234567890123" is 24 characters, so 24 bytes, right?

Comment: Oh!  The key, not the iv!